# Help with inequality in three variables subject to one constraint

Tags: inequality

For any real numbers $x, y, z>0$ such that $x+y+z=3$ the relation:

$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{y^2+1}+\frac{1}{z^2+1}\geqslant \frac{3}{2}$$

allegedly holds. Any suggestions on how to prove this? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post. Along with this, MathJax formatting is allowed in titles.

Comment: Thanks for the information , actually I'm not new , but I'm posting from a different device I'm completely aware of the rules but this is the first time I'm posting from a phone and it's not easy for me to type on phones, that's why the post was  minimalistic

Comment: @KarimKamil That isn't justification not to follow the etiquette in this site.  Anyway, all I will say is AM-GM gives $$1-\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\geqslant 1 - \frac{x}2$$ - using my phone.

Comment: "but I'm posting from a different device".  Why not delete the query yourself and then post later when you are not handicapped?  Also, although I can **guess** what $\sum \frac{1}{a^2 + 1}$ represents, personally, I will not go near a problem where I have to guess the intent of the question.

Comment: Thanks macavity , but I'm an OG , new to smartphones as Well, thanks for the hint, bear with me this first time, all

Comment: By looking at the plot of $1/(x^2+1)$ try to discover an easy but reasonably good linear lower bound of the form $1/(x^2+1)\geq px+q$ for $x\geq 0$ for some constants $p,q$. Then add them up and you should get what you need.

Comment: @Macavity Interesting observation that you make: the problem reduces to the case of only $2$ variables in the mean inequality and thus the problem inequality is valid over arbitrary (commutative and totally) ordered fields.